# Lexical issue - the words "close" and "far" in terms of time

Tags: word-usage, time-words, confusable, distance-expression, lexical-verbs

I need some help with a lexical issue. In my native language we have one word that means "close" both in terms of distance (meters etc) and in terms of distance in time. The same goes for "far" and everything related. So it's very difficult for  me do distinguish.

What words could be used to say **close** in terms of time, and what in terms of distance? Are some of them interchangable, or only reserved for one meaning? The same goes for **far**. How do you distinguish? I'd be grateful for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

TIME: close and far can be used with time

- It was **nowhere near** 8:00 pm. [for far from a specific time.]
- It was far from 8:00 pm when we started.
- It was close or closer to 7:30 when we left. [close to a time]

Close to a time and nowhere near a time [or far from a time.]

Otherwise, ***close*** and *far* apply to distances, for sure.

Comment: Worth noting that *things* either *are **coming soon*** (time) or *are **close*** (distance).

Answer (score 0):

In English "close" and "far" almost always refer to distance.

The closest common words that express that idea for time are "soon", and "later" or "eventually"

If you look up close/far in a thesaurus you'll find plenty of other options for distance, and if you look up soon/later/eventually you'll find other options for time.

Sometimes people might talk about time as a physical space, and might use distance words to refer to time. For example "The time to worry about that is far in the future" or "The party starts close to the time we're supposed to be at dinner".

I can't think of a use case where I'd use a time word to express distance.

Comment: People might use time phrases informally to express the distance between two places in terms of how long it would take to get from one to the other. For example "I live about a quarter of an hour from the station".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the adverb "nearly" for time and distance, as in these examples:

1. It is *nearly* time for dinner.
2. We are *nearly* there.

"Approaching" is also a good word for something becoming closer both in distance and in time, such as:

1. We are now *approaching* the airport.
2. The Christmas season is *approaching*.

Lexico defines "approaching" here: 
https://www.lexico.com/definition/approaching
They describe it as an adjective "Coming nearer in distance or time.
‘an approaching car’
‘He warned of an approaching crisis.'"

"Long" and "short" can also be used to express time and distance.

1. It will be a *long* time before we get there.
2. It is a *long* way to Florida.
3. We will arrive in a *short* time.
4. We will arrive *shortly*/in a *short* time.

The English language contains a rich vocabulary. I imagine it could be very overwhelming to learn it. As a native English speaker, I can safely say that I would not want to have to learn it as an adult! Reading will help you greatly, and you will discover many ways to express yourself. Good luck on your journey!